How can I add a class name to an existing class name of a button on click event in JavaScript?
I have a form that sends an email upon clicking a button. However, while the email is being sent, the button remains active, allowing users to click it multiple times, which interrupts the email-sending process. I want to add a 'disabled' class to the button as soon as it's clicked. I attempted to achieve this with the following code, but it doesn't work.
Please assist me with this problem.I tried the following codes
<div class="d-grid mt-3">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="authoriseUser" id="authoriseUser" onclick="disableBTN()">Enroll New Admin <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt ms-1"></i></button>
</div>

// JS & Jquery Code that I Tried are in the following order

// First Attempt - didn't work
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#authoriseUser").on('click',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('btn btn-primary')
            $(this).addClass('btn btn-primary disabled')
        });
    });
</script>

//Second Attenpt - didn't Work
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#authoriseUser").on('click',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('btn btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-primary disabled');
        });
    });
</script>

//Third Attempt - Didn't Work
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#authoriseUser").on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', true); 
        });
    });
</script>


Adding a class name "disabled" won't do anything unless your own code assures that it does. Setting the "disabled" property on the DOM element, however, will work, as your third code attempt does. (Yours sets the attribute instead of the property, but even that should work.)

The property disabled is defined in the CSS and Js file which disables the button when the class is applied. Could you please suggest some assistance to apply the "disabled" property on the DOM element?

Have you determined whether your event handler functions are being called? It's your code, and you are the only person who can interactively debug it.

Don't use attr when you should use prop:  .prop() vs .attr().

Removing all the detritus (and attr/prop not withstanding), all options work fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/za1gsj0L/   You don't need to remove existing classes to use jquery's addClass - it's literally add, not set.

if it's not working for you, then there is some other issue that has not been included in the question - eg what does disableBTN()?

@VIVEKROBINKUJUR  you need to add form submission jQuery code too. so that we can suggest when to remove the disable class

It is generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers.
Without jQuery and using event delegation disabling/enabling a button after click is as easy as:


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const authBtn = evt.target.closest("#authoriseUser");
  const reactivate = evt.target.closest("#reactivateAuthBttn");
  console.clear();
  
  if (authBtn) {
    // ... your actions after click
    console.log(`clicked/deactivated button#authoriseUser`);
    return authBtn.disabled = true;
  }
  
  if (reactivate) {
    console.log(`reactivated button#authoriseUser`);
    return document.querySelector("#authoriseUser").disabled = false;
  }
}
<!-- cleared for demo -->
<div>
  <button id="authoriseUser"
    >Enroll <i>New Admin</i></button>
    
  <button id="reactivateAuthBttn"
    >Reactivate enroll button</button>  
</div>




Thanks @KooiInc
I appreciate your assistance. The solution worked perfectly, just as needed. Thank you.

@VIVEK ROBIN KUJUR: please don't forget to accept this answer if it solved the problem (and optionally give it an upvote). This will help other users to find a helpful/working answer (AI spam - you know?).
